# Backbone.js sync() can't find the url property

Tags: backbone.js

With this contrived example code:

```
var Product = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: '_id',
  url: '/rest/product',
});

var Cart = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Product,
  url: '/rest/cart',
});

p1 = new Product({name: 'Keyboard'});
p2 = new Product({name: 'Mouse'});

c = new Cart();
c.add([p1, p2]);
c.sync();
```

I see `Error: A "url" property or function must be specified` There are tons of posts revolving around this same error message, but all the ones I've found are the result of, aptly, not having a url property or function defined somewhere along the way.

I feel as if I've missed a linking step somewhere - maybe I'm implicitly relying on a "magic" connection/callback/property/attribute that Backbone.js doesn't actually set automatically?

Comment: Using `fetch()` should take care of it.

Comment: @editor how so? I can call c.fetch() (which works, by the way) but that doesn't change the behavior of sync().

Comment: I added an answer to this below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd first take a step back and examine your use case and the schema you have chose. You're clearly trying to add products to a user's shopping cart.

The issue I see is that you've made the cart a collection. I'd suggest making cart a model that contains a collection of products.

```
var ProductCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : Product
});

var Cart = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url : '/rest/cart',
    defaults : {
        products : new ProductCollection()
    }
});
```

With this new schema, you can do:

```
var c = new Cart();
c.get('products').add([p1, p2]);
c.save();
```

An added benefit of this schema is that you can include additional data attributes to your cart, such as the customer ID, when the cart was created, etc.

Comment: Ahhh, and see - there's my disconnect! I had erroneously been thinking that Collections were not only a convenient aggregate for Models regarding business logic, but that they also were designed to keep their contents consistent with the storage layer. Good call, this makes a lot more sense now!

Comment: The basic idea here isn't bad, but don't use this code directly!  I think @anushr that you're not aware of some of BB's limitations.  For one, that code will share the same ProductCollection with every Cart, because BB defaults do NOT do inheritance; they're just shallow clones, which means that any objects in them aren't cloned.  Also, in that code products won't get saved when you call `c.save()`.  Backbone has no code (that I'm aware of) to invoke save on a model's attributes.  If you want that, you must add it yourself (eg. by overriding save on Cart to call invoke('save') as I suggested).

Comment: I guess a couple of caveats are in order. This solution assumes that your products already exist (that's the point of a shopping cart, to purchase existing products -- not create new ones). The instantiation of the products were merely to showcase the scenario. @machineghost is right in that attributes defined in the prototype of any JS object will not clone, they will reference. This solution assumes that each user only has one shopping cart (it's on the client side after all), so you would not have the issue of conflicting carts.

Comment: Good call, I had the same design problem.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think you should be calling `sync` directly; I think what you're looking for instead is `c.fetch()` (or `p1.save(); p2.sav2()`, depending on which direction you're trying to send data).  Sync is just what Backbone uses internally to do its `fetch`/`save` (and if you want to change the AJAX details of *how* it does them, then sync exists for you to overwrite, but otherwise you shouldn't need it).

If you want to conveniently save every model in a collection you can do so with the Underscore built-in-to-Collection method "invoke" (you should be able to do `c.save()`, but I guess you can't):

```
 c.invoke('save');
```

Comment: There is no `collection.save()`, only `model.save()` in accordance with REST. You are correct about erroneously calling `collection.sync()` though.

Comment: @PeterLyons so if I'm not to be calling collection.sync() directly, what is my alternative?

Comment: `collection.fetch()` as @machineghost points out. There are 3 main methods you call in backbone to interact with the server: `collection.fetch()`, `model.fetch()`, or `model.save()`. Those each call `Backbone.sync` with the appropriate parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot collection has no save.  To simulate one, you can just invoke save on every model: `c.invoke('save');`.  I'll edit my answer to say as much.

Answer (score 1):

The `sync()` method is merely [a proxy](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html#section-34) for `Backbone.sync`.

`fetch()` and `save()` are a convenience method for `sync()`, allowing you to assume the first `sync()` argument ('read', 'patch', 'update', etc.) is a given.

To call this yourself, you need to match the method signature for this method in order to call it directly:

```
Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options)
```

Here's how `fetch()` does it (note the passed 'read' parameter, as well as the `this` reference to the model:

```
this.sync('read', this, options);
```

Here's how `save()` does it:

```
 method = this.isNew() ? 'create' : (options.patch ? 'patch' : 'update');
 if (method === 'patch') options.attrs = attrs;
 xhr = this.sync(method, this, options);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `save()` in this case as opposed to `sync()`

`save()` essentially does the work of `Backbone.sync()` via proxy but should automatically grab the attributes from the caller of `save`.

When calling `sync()` even as a method from the model/collection, you need to provide the model you wish to sync() as the second parameter.

So, `myModel.sync('PUT',myModel)` will work. In your case specifically, `c.sync('PUT',c)`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot save a Collection this way; it is not RESTful, since REST is all about transferring the state of a (single) model. So it makes sense that Backbone.Collection doesn't support `save()`.

One solution is to call `.invoke('save')` on the collection, as @machineghost suggested, but **note** that this will result in discrete request for every single model in the Collection! If you have more than a couple models to save, this is probably not a good idea.

But you can always save a Backbone.Model... so why not make one?

```
var Wrapper = Backbone.Model.extend({
   url: 'api/endpoint'
});
var wrapper = new CollectionWrapperModel({
    cart: c.models
}); 
wrapper.save();
```

Or, more succinctly:

```
var wrapper = new (Backbone.Model.extend({url: 'api/endpoint'}))({cart: c});
wrapper.save();
```

Note that the server would then receive a POST or PUT message with a single property named `cart`, an array of multiple models, which would need to be processed appropriately.

I realize that the questioner found a different solution for his problem, but hopefully this will help someone.